Origin of the phrase "Xs and the Ys who love them"
I was just writing something, and the stock phrase "Xs and the Ys who love them" popped into my head (where X can represent pretty much any noun and Y any animate noun).  Where did this phrase first appear?  It has been used pretty broadly for my entire life, but I am wondering if its origin has any undesirable connotations.
For example, here are some top hits from Google:

"Bad" Books and the Readers Who Love Them.
The Pets We Love and the Pests That Love Them.
Men Who Hate Women and the Women Who Love Them.
Buff Celebrity Men and the Little Dogs Who Love Them.


There appears to have been an avalanche of such constructions in the late 1970s, before which time occurrences were sporadic and quite rare. I will try to write a more carefully researched answer to this question in the next few days, if I have time to do so.

This is not a "stock phrase" - it is a simple combination of words. The earliest that I can find the construction used is in "The Man about Town, Volumes 1-2" By Cornelius Webbe (1839)

Therefore are they calm, unimpassioned, serious, thoughtful, meditative, deliberative, men; and
therefore do they put their hearts into their calling,
and love their good old books, and those who love
them ... The Man about Town, Volumes 1-2 By Cornelius Webbe

Obviously, as there is nothing to indicate that this was a new construction, the phrase existed before that date in speech.

I'm not a linguist, so "stock phrase" is probably the wrong term.  I mean that it is a construction which is commonly paraphrased.  It appears frequently in book and article titles, for example.

I've thought about this for a couple of minutes, and I am not sure if this is an example.  First, it's not clear whether the final "them" is referring to the men or the books; for it to be an instance of my the phrase in my question, it would have to be the men.  Second, usually X is introduced immediately before Y and there is some surprise or contrast involved.

For example, here are some top hits from Google:
"Bad" Books and the Readers Who Love Them.
The Pets We Love and the Pests That Love Them.
Men Who Hate Women and the Women Who Love Them.
Buff Celebrity Men and the Little Dogs Who Love Them.

It's a cliche that has become common in book and article titles. Kind of like "X for Dummies".

Sure. But who coined it? How did it become so popular?
